# Pausing docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

what does it mean to pause a container? Especially, what does it mean to pause a process?

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/pause/

Answer (score 2):

According to the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pause/) the docker-compose pause command does this:

```
The docker pause command suspends all processes in the specified containers. 
On Linux, this uses the cgroups freezer. Traditionally, when suspending a process the SIGSTOP signal is used, which is observable by the process being suspended. 
With the cgroups freezer the process is unaware, and unable to capture, that it is being suspended, and subsequently resumed. On Windows, only Hyper-V containers can be paused.
```

Answer (score 2):

These is what [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pause/) says:

> The docker pause command suspends all processes in the specified containers. On Linux, this uses the cgroups freezer. Traditionally, when suspending a process the SIGSTOP signal is used, which is observable by the process being suspended. With the cgroups freezer the process is unaware, and unable to capture, that it is being suspended, and subsequently resumed. On Windows, only Hyper-V containers can be paused.

So it means that the processes in the container stop running, and they are able to be resumed later.